# How to set size width of customize fragment tab with adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I already create eash tab with customize tab textviw, here my code:

```
private void setupTabIcons() {

    TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.schedulestab2, null);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

    TextView tabThree = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.schedulestab3, null);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabThree);

    TextView tabFour = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.schedulestab4, null);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(tabFour);
}
```

the on my layout textview for customize tab :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/schedulestab3"
android:layout_width="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:foregroundGravity="top"
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
android:text="@string/fa_chevron_left"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:textSize="18dp"
app:layout_anchorGravity="right" />
```

i've been try to change width from properties but not lucky me, there is not working..., this tab just show chevron right fontawesome, but tab width too width for 1 character....

Comment: what is ** tab width too width for 1 character** means.?

Comment: i have 3 tab with titile : title one is icon prev "<" , title two Schedules today, nad title 3 is icon next ">" on my tab title 1 and 3 i try wrap_content but not working...

Comment: this the screenshoot [link]http://imradgondol.kkp.go.id/images/Screenshot_2017-08-18-10-16-36.png